# VBA Not recognizing "If" statement conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use "If" logic in Excel VBA but the script is always selecting the 1st option for two areas, even if the statement is not correct.

The point of the code is if the word "Rate" appears at one location on the screen, then certain output should be created. If it finds it in a different location, then a different output should be created. Currently, it is ready the first "If" statement and the pulling that output even though the first statement is not correct.

Using the example below, The word "Rate" appears at row, column (4,20) on the screen but the statement is creating output like it is at (4,16) and therefore pulling the output from (4,27) instead of (4,31). I have switched the order around and it always uses the first option regardless of if it is a correct statement.

I abbreviated the code as much as possible. I had both Dim'd as a string but changed RateName to Variant to see if that would fix the issue but it did not.

```
Dim RateName As Variant
Dim Curr As String

If Session.FindText("Rate", 4, 16, 4) Then
   RateName = Trim(Session.GetDisplayText(4, 27, 20)) 'R name for Amt Add, Amt Off, Buy/Get
ElseIf Session.FindText("Rate", 4, 20, 4) Then
   RateName = Trim(Session.GetDisplayText(4, 31, 20)) 'R name for Flat Amount, Pct Off
End If

If Session.FindText("Rate", 4, 16, 4) Then
   Curr = Trim(Session.GetDisplayText(4, 58, 3)) 
ElseIf Session.FindText("Rate", 4, 20, 4) Then
   Curr = Trim(Session.GetDisplayText(4, 62, 3)) 
End If
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong since I have similar logic in place elsewhere and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of VBA, returning something different to 0 is not TRUE. You get true when you use some operator

```
If Session.FindText("Rate", 4, 16, 4) = "some text/value" Then
If Session.FindText("Rate", 4, 16, 4) <> "some text/value" Then
If Session.FindText("Rate", 4, 16, 4) >= "some text/value" Then
If Session.FindText("Rate", 4, 16, 4) <= "some text/value" Then
```

Also, if the text returned is `"True"` or `"False"` for the `IF` in VBA is just a text, not `TRUE` or `FALSE`

**Edit #1** because of your comment...

And you can use this:

```
If Session.FindText("Rate", 4, 16, 4) = Empty Then 
   'some code if the logical test is true
else 
   'some code if the logical test is false
end if
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am not entirely sure I understand though. Since the If statement is not correct, since "Rate" doesn't exist where the script first looks for it, wouldn't it then move on to the Else If? The output result is going to vary so I am not sure that I could use an operator. I tried to use `If Session.FindText("Rate", 4, 16, 4) <>"" Then` but I got a mismatch type error. Thanks again.

Comment: The recommended edit sort of worked. It solved the problem until I changed the situation in which the word "Rate" would appear at (4,20). Then the output ran into the same issue as before.